# MongoDB driver - include only one element from document

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Say I have a document as this:

```
{_id:"5ac79bf31d413a65dbf9427c", username: "Carlos", scores: ["A","A"]}
```

How would I perform a projection to retrieve only the "scores" from the document?

I've tried it like this:

```
BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse("5ac79bf31d413a65dbf9427c"));    
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("scores").Slice("scores", -1);

BsonDocument document = mongoDB.GetConnection().Find(filter).Project(projection).First().AsBsonDocument;
```

I still get the whole document back however.
Any ideas help, thanks!

Comment: I do not see any issue in the query and it should return "scores" and the "_id" field in the document. but you are saying you are also getting the "username" key as well...

Comment: Yes, looks like the slice was the issue. I'll post my solution, I got it to work after removing the Slice from the projection

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, turns out the Slice was unnecessary and would break the projection:

```
BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse("5ac79bf31d413a65dbf9427c"));
ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("scores");

BsonDocument document = mongoDb.GetConnection().Find(filter).Project(projection).First().AsBsonDocument;
```